# Records read from an external file are written to JDBC twice

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, resultset

The main reason this problem baffles me is because I even included a piece of code that prevents records from being added if they already exist. And I'm almost certain the update just gets executed twice, for some reason. I've also checked that the method calling the FillDatabase method isn't in some kind of loop, but it's just the basic public method that gets executed when the class is instantiated. And it's only instantiated once.

So here's the code of my database filling method that seems to add each record twice in a row.

```
    public void FillDatabase(String filename) {
    try {
        Statement statement = dbConnection.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM OTH";
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);

        resultSet.first();

        String file = "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\" + filename +".sql";

        try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            for(String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
                line = line.substring(line.indexOf("VALUES") + 7, line.length() - 2);
                String[] parts = line.split(",");

                parts[1] = parts[1].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[2] = parts[2].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[3] = parts[3].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[4] = parts[4].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[5] = parts[5].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[6] = parts[6].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[7] = parts[7].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[8] = parts[8].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[9] = parts[9].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[10] = parts[10].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[11] = parts[11].replaceAll("'", "");
                parts[12] = parts[12].replaceAll("'", "");

                resultSet.last();
                int resultSetSize = resultSet.getRow();
                resultSet.first();

                boolean addToDatabase = true;

                for (int i = 0; i < resultSetSize; i++) {
                    if (resultSet.getString("filename").equals(parts[9])) { // If duplicate has been found
                        addToDatabase = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    resultSet.next();
                }

                if (addToDatabase) {
                    resultSet.moveToInsertRow();

                    resultSet.updateString("entity", parts[1].replaceAll("'", ""));
                    resultSet.updateFloat("s_val", Float.parseFloat(parts[2].replaceAll("'", "")));
                    resultSet.updateString("bdate", parts[3].replaceAll("'", ""));
                    resultSet.updateString("edate", parts[4].replaceAll("'", ""));
                    resultSet.updateInt("il", Integer.parseInt(parts[5].replaceAll("'", "")));
                    resultSet.updateInt("ih", Integer.parseInt(parts[6].replaceAll("'", "")));
                    resultSet.updateInt("jl", Integer.parseInt(parts[7].replaceAll("'", "")));
                    resultSet.updateInt("jh", Integer.parseInt(parts[8].replaceAll("'", "")));
                    resultSet.updateString("filename", parts[9].replaceAll("'", ""));
                    resultSet.updateString("source", parts[10].replaceAll("'", ""));
                    resultSet.updateString("contact", parts[11].replaceAll("'", ""));
                    resultSet.updateString("email", parts[12].replaceAll("'", ""));

                    resultSet.insertRow();
                }
            }

            statement.close();
            resultSet.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        System.out.println(err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

I could directly run the SQL file that is being used and it would work if the table had the right amount of columns, but the SQL file takes into account for columns that I do not need. So that is why I've included a bufferedreader which reads and separates each line of the .sql file. This is all working just fine because every value is assigned to it's corresponding column. The problem arises when I add the records to the database after that, because they get added twice instead of once. I should clarify that it's not two values being added to one column of the same row, but two identical rows are being added to the database.

My best guess is that perhaps a try-catch inside a try catch is causing the problem. Or because I'm pulling the table into a ResultSet, which I then edit before updating the table again, instead of just adding records with "INSERT INTO OTH". But this kind of method has worked for me in the past, especially when working with C#, so it shouldn't be the cause of this problem, I'm guessing.

Comment: Although it's not related to original question, but you can replace ' before splitting the string. This could help you save some LOC, which are redundant.

Comment: Please don't substantially edit your question that invalidates existing answers or changes the scope of your question. If you found a solution, then post an answer with your solution, don't edit your question and replace it with your 'answer'. If you want to provide more information, edit your question and **add** information. If you have a followup question, post a new question. I have rolled back your last edit.

Answer (score 0):

In java **arrays are zero based**.

In your code I see that you start from position 1.

So, check if the *filename* is really present in the position 10 (`parts[9]` is the 10th parts) or in position 9 and eventually change `parts[9]` to `parts[8]`.

Comment: I skip position parts[0] because it's a value that I had no use for in my table, but one that I might have to use in the future. So it was a conscious decision to start at 1 instead of 0. And the recordvalues themselves are all placed in the right columns of the row. But it's the entire row that gets added twice to the database, which is the problem.

Comment: And just to get this thought out of the way, I've checked this again and it is indeed the value that I need. Also, when I run the program again after the database has already been filled, it will not add any new record, so the bit of code that handles prevention of double records does work. The records only get added when they're missing, but the problem is that they're added twice, if found missing. And the FillDatabase method is the only method in my program that handles database insertion, so it must be located within the code that I've posted.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the external SQL file that I was reading from contained duplicate rows of every line. So my code wasn't actually causing it to be inserted twice.

Although the code that handled checking for duplicates before adding a new row failed to detect the duplicates even though it was checking the same ResultSet I was adding new rows to.

There must be some error that doesn't update the resultset before adding another line, because the duplicates are never detected when I added records to the empty database, but once it is filled, any additional runs will detect duplicates & prevent more duplicates from being added.